# Prevent crawler from changing table properties

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a glue table created by a crawler with org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe property as default. I change that to use org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerDe, but the crawler is reverting that change when it runs. What configuration do I set with the crawler preventing it from doing that?

The file format CSV with double quotes(") and \ as escape character when (") is part of the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is unfortunately not possible. Crawlers manage tables, and you can't make manual changes to the tables that are managed by a crawler – changes will be overwritten, and it's a feature, not a bug.

I think that in many situations it can be useful to use a crawler as a one-off thing to create a first version of a table, if you aren't entirely sure about the schema. However, after that initial run the crawler is of limited use, and is often even a problem, like in your case.

My advice is to turn off the crawler, make your change to OpenCSVSerDe, and never turn the crawler on again. If you used the crawler to also add new partitions to your table, I suggest looking in to [Partition Projection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html), which is a cheaper option that will also make new partitions immediately available.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Theo is incorrect. It is in fact possible to configure a Glue Crawler to ignore certain tables and prevent any modifications to their catalogs upon subsequent runs.

For example, when defining a Glue Crawler via Terraform, add the following properties to its definition to ensure the crawler only logs rather than makes changes to any existing tables:

```
schema_change_policy {
    delete_behavior = "LOG"
    update_behavior = "LOG"
}
```

You can also play around with the `recrawl_policy` option, I have set it up to only crawl newly added folders in an S3 bucket:

```
# Crawl only folders that were added since the last crawler run

recrawl_policy {
  recrawl_behavior = "CRAWL_NEW_FOLDERS_ONLY"
}
```